# How to know if AngularJS filtered and limited lists lengths are the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show an alert in case a filtered and limited list has elements not being shown. I'm looking for a good performing solution, as these lists will be really long.

Here is what I have from now:

```
<div class="list_item" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.list | filter: $ctrl.responsiveFilter | limitTo: 6 as results track by $index">
    <label ng-click="$ctrl.handle_list_click()">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
        <div class="fake_label" >
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="list_item too_many"
     ng-repeat-end
     ng-if="results.length > 6">
    <div class="fake_label">
        {{results.length}} matches... Please, filter out.
    </div>
</div>
```

But the results contains the elements after being filtered and also limited. If I move the `as results` just before the `limitTo`, it just breaks.

The **condition** I want to detect show the alert would be: **if the limited list's length and the filtered list's length are different, then show the alert**.

I don't mind using something else, instead of the `as results`, just wonder if there is a way to detect that condition.

**Edit:** the problem right now is that `results.length` gives me the amount of elements after applying the limit, while what I need is the amount just after the filter, but before the limit. I know how to do this by deleting the `limitTo` sentence, but then there are too many results on the list...

Comment: It's a very simple comparison `results.length-limit >0` or even `ng-if="results.length-limit"`. Just use a scope variable instead of hard code the limit

Comment: I think in this case you're better off watching for changes and constructing a filtered list yourself, then iterate over it as well as use it for your condition check. - e.g. $scope.$watchCollection('list', rf => filteredList = ... )

Comment: Something like `$ctrl.list.length > results.length`?

Comment: @charlietfl I think you are not understanding the real condition. I've added some more explanation at the end.

Comment: do your own filter that also manages the limiting then you have everything you need in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to duplicate the repeat and use it to count the filtered elements. At first, I expected this to be quite slow but I'm really surprised of how fast it runs, probably because there is not really much `DOM` manipulation.

```
<div class="list_item" ng-if="false" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.list | filter: $ctrl.responsiveFilter as count track by $index">
</div>

<div class="list_item" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.list | filter: $ctrl.responsiveFilter | limitTo: 6 as results track by $index">
    <label ng-click="$ctrl.handle_list_click()">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
        <div class="fake_label" >
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="list_item too_many"
     ng-repeat-end
     ng-if="count.length > results.length">
    <div class="fake_label">
        {{count.length}} matches... Please, filter out.
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you have an `ng-if` hidden loop to count the filtered elements and another one to count and paint the limited list. All you have to do is to use these data to create the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newapp = angular.module('someapp',[]);
newapp.service('limitcheck', [function(){
 return {
   checkLimit : function (arr) {
     if (arr.length > 6) {
       alert('The array has more than 6 entries');
      }
    }
  };
}]);
newapp.filter('dummyfilter',['limitcheck',function(limitcheck){
 return function (input) {
   //do your filtering here
    limitcheck.checkLimit(input);
    return input;
  }
}]);
newapp.controller('something', ['$scope',function(scope){
  //This will trigger alert since it contains more than 6 entries
  scope.alist = ['me','you','someone','anyone', 'noone','everyone','villain']; 
  //this will not
  //scope.alist = ['me','you','someone','anyone', 'noone','everyone']; 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='someapp'>
  <div ng-controller='something'>
    <div ng-repeat='person in alist | dummyfilter | limitTo :6'>
      {{person}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried and achieved the result by using a service and a filter combination

I hope this helps